# Composition of functions of bounded variation is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Measure is the Lebesgue measure. It would be enough to show that for any $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$, $\{x|f\circ g(x) \leq \alpha\}$ is measurable for $f,g$ bounded variation functions from $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. I don't immediately see how bounded variation applies to the above definition of measurable. Is there perhaps a different definition of measurable function that would be more useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function of bounded variation is the difference of monotone functions. And every monotone function is Borel measurable. Hence a function of bounded variation is Borel measurable. Finally, the composition of Borel measurable functions is Borel measurable.